# drag and drop with haxe nme

Tags: android, ios, drag-and-drop, touch, haxe

i'm trying to make a simple drag and drop in haxe NME targeting touch devices, but i'm unable to.

i tried, startDrag(), a combination of mouseDown, mouseUp and mouseMove,another combination of TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN,TouchEvent.TOUCH_END,TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE and startDragTouch() etc.. but in the first 3 cases, the app crashes in androin, and in the last one, i'm getting:

```
 nme.display.Sprite has no field startTouchDrag
```

at the moment of compilation.

Anyone knows a method to have drag & drop support for touch devices in haxe NME? any hint of how this can be achieved?

Many thanks

Regards

Answer (score 0):

ok, at the end, the custom implementation with MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP and MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE worked, but i needed to use the coordinated from the passed element to get the StageX and StageY and not getting them directly from the "stage". in that way, doesn't crash.

Regards.